# SQL Server 2008 trigger throwing error when I use procedure GETDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, getdate

I am trying to create a trigger in SQL Server 2008 which inserts a row into a 2nd database after an update in the 1st database.

However I keep getting an error..

> (Procedure behaviour_alert, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Is this because of using DATETIME in the trigger.

This works as a normal query, I can't see why it won't work as a trigger. 
Can only adjust the query to choose the current datetime?

Query below

```
create trigger behaviour_alert
on [database1].[dbo].[studconduct]
for update
as
begin

declare @conductdatetime as datetime
set @conductdatetime = GETDATE()

insert into database2.dbo.behaviouralert
  select *
  from studconduct
  where curr_ind='Y'
  and cond_pts >= '5'
  and conduct_date >= @conductdatetime
```

What am I missing here, going crossed eyed looking at this. Maybe I have had too much coffee.

Edit: this is what I ended up with and it worked. I missed the END at the end of the trigger

```
create trigger behaviour_alert
    on [database1].[dbo].[studconduct]
    for update
    as
    begin
    insert into database2.dbo.behaviouralert
      select *
      from studconduct
      where curr_ind='Y'
      and cond_pts >= '5'
      and conduct_date >= datetime
    end
```

Comment: Do you really need the variable? What's wrong with `and conduct_date >= GETDATE()`?

Comment: And where is your reference to `inserted` or `deleted`... Surely you would be wise to use `inserted` and also explicitly name your columns for `insert` and `select`...

Comment: @todda.speot.is - the behaviour only happens once in a year, at end of year the table is wiped and starts again. each day and various different behaviours. a student could have multiple plus5's but different behaviours. do you think I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problems is not in GETDATE().
maybe you just forget about END in the end of trigger?

Comment: 2 pairs of eyes are better than 1. Awesome matey, thank you, missing the END.